# Bash silent error processing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, sh

I'm trying to run programs (for example `mv file1.txt file2.txt`) in my .sh script and I need to hide errors, but handle it with my script.

Currently I'm trying to do something like

```
EXECUTE="mv -v $VOL $BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT"
{
  EXEC_ERROR=$($EXECUTE)
} &2>> $LOG_FILE
if [[ -n $EXEC_ERROR ]]; then
  echo "There is an error!"
fi
```

But it doesn't work at all - it shows an error (for example `mv: cannot stat 'file1.txt': No such file or directory`) and $EXEC_ERROR variable is empty.

Is there any way to get output to variable + to log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
mv -v $VOL $BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT 2>> $LOG_FILE
if [[ ! ( $? -eq 0 ) ]] ; then
    echo "There is an error\!"
fi
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me - I still can see an error `mv: cannot stat 'file1.txt': No such file or directory` and there is no record to log file :(

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Also I found that I should use 2>> $LOG_FILE insted of &2>> $LOG_FILE

Comment: Why not `[[ $? -ne 0 ]]`? The parentheses and `!` operator seem rather verbose.  You could also simply use: `if mv -v "$VOL" "$BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT" 2>> "$LOG_FILE"; then : OK; else echo 'There is an error!'; fi` (or `if ! mv -v "$VOL" "$BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT" 2>> "$LOG_FILE"; then echo 'There is an error!'; fi`).

Answer (score 1):

Though `$?` is good for saving and processing exit codes, the `if` statement is designed to take any command, not just `[` or `[[`:

```
if ! mv -v "$VOL" "$BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT" 2>> $LOG_FILE; then
  echo "There is an error!"
fi
```

This includes saving variables:

```
if OUTPUT=$(mv -v "$VOL" "$BACKUP_YESTERDAY_CRYPT" 2>> $LOG_FILE); then
  echo ">>> $OUTPUT <<<"
fi
```

In fact, `if` can take more than one command, as its [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) describes. Documentation on boolean operators such as `!`, `&&`, and `||` is hidden within the description of [shell commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Commands), where they form pipelines (`!`) and lists (`&&`, `||`).

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
mv sourcefile destfile 2> /dev/null 1>logfile
returnstatus=`echo $?`
if [[ $returnstatus -ne 0 ]]; then 
    echo "There was an error!"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Using ``returnstatus=`echo $?` `` instead of just `returnstatus=$?` seems like overkill.